# Android ResultReceiver in multi threaded environment

Tags: android, multithreading, android-intent

I have an activity which, essentially, starts multiple threads in order to get multiple resources from network. I update the UI after receiving the notifications from these threads using ResultReceiver mechanism.
The code snippet looks like below,

```
public void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData){

    switch(resultCode){

    case 1: updateData1();
        break;

    case 2: updateData2();
        break;

    case 3: updateData3();
        break;
}
```

As, its the main thread which updates the UI elements on receiving the notifications from these threads, I was thinking it will be a good idea to make method onReceiveResult synchronized. Any comments?
Is there is anything else that should be taken care of in order keep it efficient and safe?

Comment: The data is already marshalled and signaled onto the UI thread. 'onReceiveResult' will not be entered directly from the other threads by the ResultReceiver mechanism - the call is serialized. Synchro is only required if you explicitly call the handler from the other threads.

Answer (score 0):

No, this will not help and it will block the thread. Instead run the code that will modify the UI on the UI thread, otherwise you will have problems depending on where this onReceiveResult is called...

```
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

           @Override
           public void run() {
               updateData1();
           }
});
```